# Extremum of a two variable function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

So I have the function

$f(x,y)=y^2-x^2y$ and I'm to find out the extreme values at $D=${$(x,y)\in R^2|y\ge x^2-1$}.

I figured I'd have to generate partial derivatives and I got to

$f_x(x,y)=-2xy$

$f_y(x,y)=2y-x^2$

and if I solve the functions as a pair when both are $0$, I get that $x=0, y=0$, but I'm not sure if I'm doing this right or if I am, what exactly I should tackle next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, notice that the function is unbounded above since $f(0,y)=y^2$ tends to infinity when $y \to \infty$ (satisfying the constraint $y \geq -1$).

Second, we can make a change in variables $z=x^2$ and replace $f$ by $g(y,z)=y^2-z y$ defined for the pairs $(y,z)$ such that $y+1 \geq z \geq 0$.

Consider now the expression $g(y,y+1)=y^2-(y+1)y=-y$.

This function has limit $-\infty$ when $y \to \infty$ and is therefore unbounded below. Thus the function $f(x,y)=g(y,x^2)$ has no finite lower bound.

Comment: I can certainly see the logic here, but how should I be able to figure out that "this is exactly the right way to solve a problem like this", like - is there an universal solving pattern to these or do I simply have to learn every unique case like this separately?

Comment: In general it makes sense to try obtaining a lower bound and an upper bound for any fixed $y$ (or $x$), and then to analyze how these bounds vary with $y$. This is what I did in the answer above. The problem with looking at partial derivatives is that we don't know ex ante whether a global minimum or maximum exist. In addition, the first-order conditions are of little help if an extremum is attained on the frontier of the domain (and not inside).